# Mturk: three tasks but only one HIT

Tags: mechanicalturk

How can this be done with Mechanical Turk?

1- Worker fills in an evaluation test
2- The same worker uses an online e-learning site specifically on the topics that he/she failed.
3- The same worker passes again the evaluation test in order to confirm he/she made progress.

The test and the training can both be done online. Results and communications via email.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a lot of manual work or custom programming.

You might want to use a Mechanical Turk Partner like [TurkPrime.com](https://www.turkprime.com). They work with many researchers to create customized solutions using what they call [Concierge Services](https://www.turkprime.com/Service/BusinessSolutions?heading=Concierge%20Services)".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like manual work to me as well. If you do not want to program it then the manual option is to split it into three separate HITs and add a custom [qualification](https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-understanding-requirements-and-qualifications-99a26069fba2) after the first and second HIT. These qualifications would be required to accept the second and third HIT respectively.